# Issue in loading data into Glue Table with saveAsTable from AWS Glue Job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I've got a glue table where the files are in parquet format and partitioned by two columns.
I load data by writing to the S3 bucket and then run Crawler to add the new partition information.
However, I want to write the files using bucketing. I tried the below approach.

`df.write.format("parquet").mode("append").partitionBy('x', 'y').bucketBy(5,'a').saveAsTable("db.table_name")`

I get below error: "The format of existing table is in 'HiveFileFOrmat'; it doesn't match the specified format, 'parquetDataSourceV2'

Any solutions?

`df.write.format("parquet").mode("append").partitionBy('x', 'y').bucketBy(5,'a').saveAsTable("db.table_name")`